# How to find the presence of value in my database before adding to it?

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x

I am new to SQLite Database so I can't figure what is the problem, I am willing to create a database for the list of cars and their rates present in the world.

```
    import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('Car.db')
cur= db.cursor()
var = (int)(input("How many cars you want to enter?"))
for i in range(var):
    Has = input('CAR :')
    for name in Has:
        cur.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM CARS WHERE Name = ?',(name,))
        base = cur.fetchone()[0]
        if base ==0:
            print('CAR EXISTS')
        else:
            some = input('RATE:')
            cur.execute('''INSERT INTO CARS(Name,Rate)VALUES(?,?)''',{'Name':Has,'Rate':some})
db.close()
```

I want to check whether the entered car is already present before adding to my database but when I do so it shows the following output

CAR: Audi
CAR EXISTS
CAR EXISTS
CAR EXISTS
CAR EXISTS

Thank you

edit
According to CL'S comment I inserted the statement and found that the loop is iterated over every single character like this 
CAR : Audi
A
CAR ALREADY EXISTS
u
CAR ALREADY EXISTS
and so on

I solved that but I get the same error,
Here is how I solved:

```
  for name in Has,:
```

Working code:[In addition to answer my code contained several errors so why I provided this code]

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('Cars.db')
cur= db.cursor()
var = (int)(input("How many cars you want to enter?"))
for i in range(var):
    Has = input('CAR :')
    for name in Has,:
        cur.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM CARS WHERE Name = ?',(name,))
        base = cur.fetchone()[0]
        if base>0:
            print('CAR EXISTS')
        else:
            some = input('RATE:')
            var = '''INSERT INTO CARS(Name,Rate)VALUES(?,?)'''
            cur.execute(var,(name,some))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: Print out the value of `name`.

Comment: @CL.  Could you please explain this?  name is just a variable used for iteration

Comment: Insert the statement `print(name)`.

Comment: @CL. I still get the same error can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if base ==0:
        print('CAR EXISTS')
```

When the number of rows is zero, you are printing "EXISTS".
This is wrong; when a car exists, the number of matching rows would be larger than zero.

Comment: Finally figured out, Made it working by changing if base>0. Thank you